# Grub - install and boot errors

Tags: boot, grub2

I have a problem with my boot loader. I have two systems windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04.
Today I have experienced an error while booting, grub went straight to .
I have tried several times too repair grub with boot-repair. Boot repair cant find
the grub settings. I have also reinstalled grub with no luck. Grub has shown me an
error message "permittion denied". I am quite reluctant to reinstall both of my
systems can someone advise?

Thanks

Comment: what are the commands did you try?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo update-grub
```

Did not work due, I have browsed some resources and it appeared that I did
not mount the ubuntu partition. I had also problems with mounting due to a lack
of correctly formated disk with the correct extension. I had to reinstall ubuntu
and it did the trick.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into ubuntu,open the terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>,then run the following command to update grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

It detects the os's present in the system and make them to appear on the grub.